# Wordpress bubble notification in frontend when new post is created

Tags: wordpress, notifications

I need code or a plugin with the following function:
A bubble with new post count in the mainmenu (front-end). For example if two new posts is created show it like this in the menu: Blog (2)
Show for every user: When user 1 have clicked on the new posts - user 2 still have notifications until its clicked.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at this and edit your question afterwards: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What are your conditions for a "new post"; since a visitor's last visit, since a user's last login, since a certain date?